# Module 'flutter_keyboard_visibility' not found on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

This is a simple flutter project. Android version is running without any error.

But the Problem is in ios version. Here is the screenshot of the error. [image]

I have removed the podfile and reinstall again. But no luck!!

Comment: Are you using any plugin related to keyboard? and also what version of flutter are you using?

Comment: I am not using any keyboard plugin here. This is auto-generated.

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-BD)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of `Runner.xcodeproj`

Comment: elaborate please. how??

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue by removing the module from my pubspec.yaml and adding it again.

Clean derived data manually.

`flutter pub get` (without flutter_keyboard_visibility)

```
flutter clean
```

`flutter pub get` (uncomment to reinstall it)

```
pod install
```

Launch Runner.xcworkspace
Build & Run

EDIT: If your problem is with the archive and not the run. It seems that your minimum ios version is too old. Simply increase the minimum iOS version in `Runner > Targets > Deployment Info`
(For me, iOS 11 works).

Comment: After trying all other solutions, simply updating the minimum iOS version worked for me.